# tcl code to fetch data from given file and saved on another file with particular format

Tags: tcl

I have one file data that contains a few lines in the 1st line it gives different types of voltages and after that, all the lines have block names with different voltages each voltage value split with tab either one or more than one tab in data, the example data in the file is given here:

```
Block Name  VDDQL(W)    VDDA(W) VDD(W)  VDDPLL  VDD1P2
Data IO TX  8.80E-04    3.00E-04    1.10E-03        
Data IO RX  1.88E-05    4.35E-04    6.15E-04        
WDQS    2.10E-03    9.00E-04    2.30E-03        
RDQS        1.30E-03            
TX_CLKGEN       1.20E-03    3.30E-03        
TX_CLKGEN_WDQS      1.00E-03    2.90E-03        
RX_CLKGEN       4.00E-03            
INV_32X     4.13E-04            
INV_64X     5.63E-04            
INV_128X        9.38E-04            
INV_256X        1.70E-03            
ZQ Calibration  9.60E-03            2.30E-03    
HBM3_PLL                7.50E-03    1.36E-02
SoC PLL             7.50E-03    1.36E-02
RX_VREF 3.96E-04        3.30E-06
```

and I am expecting output file data as

```
Data IO TX < 8.80E-04 3.00E-04 1.10E-03 > VDDQL(W) VDDA(W) VDD(W) 
Data IO RX < 1.88E-05 4.35E-04 6.15E-04 > VDDQL(W) VDDA(W) VDD(W) 
WDQS < 2.10E-03 9.00E-04 2.30E-03 > VDDQL(W) VDDA(W) VDD(W) 
RDQS < 1.30E-03 > VDDA(W) 
TX_CLKGEN < 1.20E-03 3.30E-03 > VDDA(W) VDD(W) 
TX_CLKGEN_WDQS < 1.00E-03 2.90E-03 > VDDA(W) VDD(W)
RX_CLKGEN < 4.00E-03 > VDDA(W) 
INV_32X< 4.13E-04 > VDDA(W) 
INV_64X < 5.63E-04 > VDDA(W) 
INV_128X < 9.38E-04 > VDDA(W) 
INV_256X < 1.70E-03  > VDDA(W) 
ZQ Calibration < 9.60E-03 2.30E-03 > VDDQL(W) VDD(W) 
HBM3_PLL < 7.50E-03 1.36E-02 > VDD(W) VDDPLL    
SoC PLL < 7.50E-03 1.36E-02 > VDDA(W) VDD(W) 
RX_VREF < 3.96E-04 3.30E-06 > VDDQL(W) VDD(W)
```

the code what i tried is

```
while {[gets $in_lib line] >=0} {
    if {[string match {*Block*} $line] == 1} {
        set input $line     
        set columns [split $input {\s+}]
        set blockName [lindex $columns 0]
        set column_1 [lindex $columns 1]
        set column_2 [lindex $columns 2]
        set column_3 [lindex $columns 3]
        set column_4 [lindex $columns 4]
        set column_5 [lindex $columns 5]
    } else {
        set lineData $line
    }   
    foreach data_line $lineData {
                set columns [split $line "\t"]
        # Extract the keyword and values
                set keyword [lindex $columns 0]
                set value1 [lindex $columns 1]
                set value2 [lindex $columns 2]
                set value3 [lindex $columns 3]
            set value4 [lindex $columns 4]
            set value5 [lindex $columns 5]
                # Print the extracted data
                set Keyword $keyword
                set Value1 $value1
                set Value2 $value2
                set Value3 $value3
                set Value4 $value4
            set Value5 $value5  
    }
    puts $Keyword
```

here i am fetching the data successfully, but after this i am struck to continue this can please help me for this, even i am new to this programming, i tried some logics but its giving error so i removed that logic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit easier if you put this in a procedure. Then, we can safely use whether there is a variable (`header` below) to decide whether we have processed the header line. That avoids having to do anything more complicated. The tab separation is convenient; we can use `split ... \t` to make a well-formed list for each line.

```
proc convert {inputChannel outputChannel} {
    while {[gets $inputChannel line] >= 0} {
        # Parse the header if we didn't already have one
        if {![info exist header]} {
            set header [split [regsub {^Block Name\s+} $line ""] \t]
            continue
        }

        # Split into block name and items
        set items [lassign [split $line \t] blockName]
        # Filter empties
        set names {}
        set realItems {}
        foreach item $items name $header {
            if {$item ne ""} {
                lappend realItems $item
                lappend names $name
            }
        }
        # Write out
        puts $outputChannel "$blockName < $realItems > $names"
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice trick of "lassign".

Answer (score 0):

Note: Use a state machine to distinguish header line from data lines.

```
set state HEAD
while { [gets $in_lib line] >= 0 } {
    switch -- $state {
        HEAD {
            if { [regexp {^\s*Block Name} $line] } {
                set field_list [lrange [split $line \t] 1 end]
                set state DATA
            }
        }
        DATA {
            set data_list [split $line \t]
            set list1 [list [lindex ${data_list} 0] <]
            set data_list [lrange ${data_list} 1 end]
            set list2 >
            foreach data ${data_list} field ${field_list} {
                if { [string length $data] > 0 } {
                    lappend list1 $data
                    lappend list2 $field
                }
            }
            puts [join [concat $list1 $list2] { }]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Give the states names. It's pretty much the same speed as numbers, and so much clearer to read.